# Dividing with precision in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a fairly small double and a fairly large double. When I divide the large one by the small one and display it with `Console.WriteLine`, it always shows exponential notation. Can I display the non exponential notation form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `Console.WriteLine` it will use a default format for the given type. The same thing you'd get if you used `ToString()` explicitly. Have you tried specifying the format, as in `number.ToString("D")`?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, here are some examples with other specifiers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx